# In ArcGis10.2 ModelBuilder: Make Output-Name in ArcGis System Tool "Featur to Raster" depending on selected field for pixel value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, feature-class

[image]

This might be easy, but I could not find a solution:

I am using the system tool "Feature to Raster" in ModelBuilder in ArcGis 10.2.

I want to substitute the name of the output raster, "RasterName", with a variable output name, depending on the selected "Field" for pixel value. It should be something like **Raster_%Field%"**, which results in "**Raster_*Used_agric_land***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Field** in the **Feature to Raster** tool must be exposed as a model variable.

Right click on the **Feature to Raster** tool >> Make Variable >> From Parameter >> Field

Once you have done that you can then set Raster_%Field%